# Generating from Dirichlet distribution with the differences in a sequence of ordered uniform

Tags: sampling, dirichlet-distribution

First, let's assume that we want to generated from a [Dirichlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution)(1,1,1,1) distribution. Would the following method be correct?:

- generate three variates from a Uniform(0,1). Call them $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$.
- then, order these such that $0 \leq x_{(1)} \leq x_{(2)} \leq x_{(3)} \leq 1$
- then, return the differences as our Dirichlet variate: $(x_{(1)}, x_{(2)}-x_{(1)}, x_{(3)}-x_{(2)}, 1-x_{(3)})$

Is this correct? I have a feeling it is correct, but I'm not sure and this does not seem to be the same as either method described on Wikipedia or any other search I did. Maybe it is slow or has other problems, but I'm curious if it is correct.

Assuming this is correct, can it be extended to non-uniform Dirichlets, such as Dirichlet(a,b,c,d)?

**Extra note**:  I am *not* simply asking how to generate a Dirichlet; there is plenty of information about that already.  I'm just curious to see if the method for uniforms can be extended.  Is there a more general method that involves drawing from a distribution, then ordering those numbers, then using the gaps?

Comment: I think this is *exactly* the "method described elsewhere", just in disguise. **Hint**: What do you know about the Poisson process?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate uniformly distributed weights that sum to unity?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14059/generate-uniformly-distributed-weights-that-sum-to-unity)

Comment: @cardinal, I can't see the relevance of Poisson. The probability of the event happening in a Poisson process in independent of how long it has been since the last event. One of the methods on Wikipedia is based on Gamma, which I know is the conjugate prior for Poisson - but I can't really see any direct connection. I can see some vague connections, but nothing that helps with Dirichlets other than Dirichlet(1,1,...)

Comment: Specifically, there is a property of the homogeneous Poisson process that often goes by the name of the *order-statistic property*. I suspect you should immediately see its relevance. In fact it can be viewed as the *intrinsic* property that leads to the definition of a Poisson process on more general spaces than the nonnegative half-line.

Comment: The previous comments were not intended to address your last question, only the first.

Comment: @cardinal, actually, I think I get some aspects of it now :-) $P(x_{(1)}, x_{(2)}, ..., x_{(n)}) = n! P(x_1)P(x_2)...P(x_n)$ assuming that the various $x$s are iid (or something like that...). So it should be trivial to start with the Dirichlet pdf and derive a number of different generation processes.

Answer (score 6):

If $Y_i$ are independent $\mathrm{Gamma}(\alpha_i,\beta)$, for $i=1,\dots,k$, then
$$ (X_1,\dots,X_k) = \left(\frac{Y_1}{\sum_{j=1}^k Y_j}, \dots, \frac{Y_k}{\sum_{j=1}^k Y_j} \right) \sim \mathrm{Dirichlet}(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_k) \, .$$
So, in R just do something like

```
rdirichlet <- function(a) {
    y <- rgamma(length(a), a, 1)
    return(y / sum(y))
}
```

And use it uniformily

```
> rdirichlet(c(1, 1, 1, 1))
[1] 0.40186737 0.03924152 0.37070316 0.18818796
```

or non-uniformily

```
> rdirichlet(c(3, 2.5, 9, 7))
[1] 0.1377426 0.1043081 0.4701179 0.2878314
```

The proof is given on page 594 of Luc Devroye's beautiful book:

http://luc.devroye.org/rnbookindex.html

P.S. Thanks to @cardinal for the R hacking tips.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `sapply` call, I don't believe; `rgamma` should allow a vector to be supplied to the parameter argument. In the special case described in the question, using `rexp` would be preferable.

Comment: `rgamma` doesn't seem to vectorize automatically.

Comment: Instead of passing 1 as the first argument, did you try passing `length(a)`?

Comment: That works! Cool! Edited.

Comment: I'm not simply looking for methods to generate a Dirichlet, it is not difficult to find information on that.  I'm specifically asking if there is a method which involves drawing a set of numbers, ordering them, and using the gaps.  Such a method works for the uniform case, I wonder if there is a more general version of this.  This is just a curiousity - in hindsight I think I shouldn't be wasting all our time with this :-)

Comment: Oh, that... Well, you could try to simulate from the $\mathrm{Dirichlet}(1,1,\dots,1)$ using your "differences of order statistics of independent uniforms $[0,1]$" method, and then use a transformation to get the general Dirichlet.

Comment: +1 for the link to Luc Devroye's book, and a clear answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U_{(1)},U_{(2)}, \ldots, U_{(n)}$ be the order statistics from $U(0,1)$ distribution. Let $W_0 = U_{(1)},W_i = U_{(i+1)}-U{(i)}$, $1 \leq i \leq n-1$.

Then $(W_0, W_1, \ldots, W_{n-1}) \sim \cal{D}(\alpha)$, a dirichlet distribution with parameter $\alpha_{n+1,1} = (1,1,\ldots,1)$. That is, $(W_0, W_1, \ldots, W_{n-1})$ is uniformly distributed in the n-dimensional simplex.

Comment: Something's not quite right here, because $U_{(n)}\ne1$ almost surely and therefore $W_0+W_1+\cdots+W_{n-1}=U_{(n)}$ does not even lie on the unit simplex.

Comment: @VitalStatistix, I think your answer is just a rephrasing of my question. Do you have a reference or proof to back up your answer?

Comment: @Aaron. This is a theorem from Probability for Statistics and Machine Learning by Anirban Dasgupta, Theorem 6.6.

Consider the joint density of order statistics of uniform 
$f(U_{(1)}, \ldots, U_{(n)})= n!$. Now make the transformations $W_0=U{(1)}, W_{(i)}=U_{(i+1)}-U_{(i)}, 1\leq i \leq n-1$, the Jacobian of the transformation is 1. We can easily see from the Change of Variable theorem that the joint density of the $W_i$'s is the following: 
$f(w_0,w_2, ..., w_{n-1})= n! \{w_i\geq 0 \forall i; w_o+\ldots+w_{n-1} \leq 1\}$ - which we recognize as the Dirichlet density function.

Comment: @Whuber: Sorry for not being clear about what I mean by uniformly distributed on unit simplex. Let us consider the simplest Dirichlet density. 

$f(x_1, x_2) \propto {x_1}^{\alpha_1-1} {x_2}^{\alpha_2-1} x_3^{\alpha_3-1}$ where, $0 \leq x_1,x_2,x_3 \leq 1; x_1+x_2+x_3 =1 $. Here, $x_1,x_2,x_3$ lie in the unit simplex but the density is on $x_1,x_2$. Let me know if I could answer your question.

Comment: Can we generalize this to Dirichlet distribution with other $\alpha$ parameters?