# How to sample from a distribution so that mean of samples equals expected value?

Tags: r, distributions, sampling, expected-value

Given a random variable $X$, how do I have obtain $N$ random variates of $X$ so that the mean value of my samples equals the expected value of $X$?

E.g. let $X$ have uniform distribution on the interval $[0, 1]$, and draw $N = 10000$ samples. We can do this in `R` using:

```
set.seed(5)
tmp_vec <- runif(10000, 0, 1)
```

However, `mean(tmp_vec)` returns `0.5018471`. I would like it so that the mean is 0.5, matching the expected value. Should I rescale the sampled values of `tmp_vec`?

Comment: I have a function $\sum(f(x))$ over a vector $x$. I want to make a statement concerning how this sum changes when $x$ is randomly perturbed, so that the perturbations follow a known distribution. To do this I am going to sample the sum repeatedly over different draws from the distribution, however, I don't want to have to factor in the variance of the draws into the computation of the sum.

Comment: Or rather, I might sample the distribution once, and then permute the pertubations over the vector $x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a [related question,](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/243260/7224) namely how to simulate an iid random sample $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)\sim f$, under the constraint that its sum $X_1+\cdots+X_n$ is fixed to an arbitrary value $s_0$, I [showed](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/243516/7224) that the density of that sample is given by
$$(X_1,\ldots,X_n)\sim f(x_1)\cdots f(x_{n-1})f(s_0-x_1-\cdots-x_n)\mathbb{I}_{s_0-x_1-\cdots-x_{n-1}}(x_n)$$

> **Note:** Under the constraint the sample is no longer independent but the
>   observations are identically distributed, despite the apparent
>   asymmetry in the above.

For instance, a Uniform sample with fixed average $0.5$ would have the joint density
$$(U_1,\ldots,U_N)\sim \prod_{i=1}^{N-1}\mathbb{I}_{(0,1)}(u_i)\mathbb{I}_{1/2}(u_1+\cdots+u_N)$$
which can simulated by Gibbs sampling or another MCMC algorithm like RWMH. When using Gibbs sampling, the $N-1$ first coordinates of the sample can be simulated one at a time with
$$U_i|U_{-i}\sim \mathbb{I}_{(0,1)}(u_i) \mathbb{I}_{(0,1)}(s_0-u_1-\cdots-u_i-\cdots-u_{n-1})=\mathbb{I}_{(\max\{0,s_0-1-\sum_{j\ne i,n}u_j\},\min\{1,s_0-\sum_{j\ne i,n}u_j\})}(u_i)$$
An R implementation looks like this code:

```
n=3;T=1e4
s0=.5 #fixed average
sampl=matrix(s0,T,n)
for (t in 2:T){
 sampl[t,]=sampl[t-1,]
 for (i in 1:(n-1)){
  sampl[t,i]=runif(1,
  min=max(0,n*s0-sum(sampl[t,c(-i,-n)])-1),
  max=min(1,n*s0-sum(sampl[t,c(-i,-n)])))
 sampl[t,n]=n*s0-sum(sampl[t,-n])}}
```

with the following marginals on the $U_i$'s:

[image: Histograms of the three components of a constrained uniform sample with fixed average 0.5]

> **Note:** One can easily modify the above R code to impose an average of $s_0=0.05$ or $s_0=0.975$ on the sample.

Comment: Thanks! Why is this different from just taking the sample, and then rescaling it?

Comment: If you rescale your sample, it no longer has the original distribution. Nor does it enjoy the proper conditional distribution. You thus end up with an usually unspecified distribution. Take e.g. a Normal sample. When rescaled to have fixed average and empirical variance, it is no longer Normal.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you can achieve that. `runif` is a pseudo-random number generator that produces uniformly distributed random variables. It does not produce random variable with an exact mu that is equal to what you specified. 0.0518 is a pretty good mu. 
The same is true for the family of functions including `rnorm`, `rexp`, `rpois` etc.

but try this, it should work:

```
runif2<-function(n,min,max){((min+max)/2)+sqrt((max-min)/12)*scale(runif(n))}
r <- runif2(100,0,1)
mean(r) #0.5
```

Just keep in mind that this sample is now different than `runif` because you used 'scale'. It does not have the same properties as your original distribution and it may or may not pass tests for randomness.

Answer (score -1):

Only an infinite sized sample would guarantee an exact result and that is not possible. However, you can set a limit on how close to the "real" mean you would like to get or which is the smallest deviation you are ready to accept in 95% of the cases. The key to that ist the standard error of the mean.

$SE = \frac{s}{sqrt(n)}$

with s being the standard deviation (for large $n$ there is not much point in distinguishing between sample of distribution) you can resolve that to

$n=(\frac{s}{SE})^2$

and thus compute the minimum number fo any given Standard Error that you are willing to accept.

The Wikipedia is actually quite good at this entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error